# Выбор случайного цвета из списка

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть програма на WinForms, она считывает цвет в picturebox, куда нажал пользователь и делат область с этим цветом прозрачной. У меня есть список цветов (150+). Хочу, чтобы програма выбирала случайный из них и просила пользователя кликунть на него, если кликнет не правильно, то програма не засчитает этот клик, потом задаётся следующий цвет и так определённое количетво разов. Правда не очень представлсяю, как это реализовать. Думал, чтобы записать в отдельный файл огромную конструкцию из if-else-if или switch и подключить его в програму, после чего каким-то образом выбирать случайный, но мне кажется, что это довольно костыльный способ. Есть ли у кого-то предложения, как по вашему мнению будет лучше сделать это?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");


    public Graphics pctMap;
    public bool CheckClick = false;
   

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoSize = true;
        pctMap = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        pictureBox1.Size = ClientSize;

    }

  
    public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs rato = e as MouseEventArgs;
        int x = rato.X * myBitmap.Width / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
        int y = rato.Y * myBitmap.Height / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;
        Color backColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        textBox1.Text = backColor.ToString();
        CheckClick = !CheckClick;
            if (CheckClick) 
        {

            if (backColor == Color.FromArgb(255, 79, 28, 16))
                {
                myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColor);
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myBitmap = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Пытался изложить максимально кртако, но как-то много текста получилось.

Comment: А где список цветов то? В чем вопрос? Как выбрать случайный? Заведите глобальный генератор `private static readonly Random rndGen = new Random()`. Затем заведите глобально случайный цвет `private Color randomColor`. И где-нибудь в коде `randomColor = myColors[rndGen.Next(0, myColors.Count)]`. Останется только сравнить `if (someColor == randomColor) { ... }`.